# Obtaining k-reciprocal nearest neighbours

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background information on my question:**

Two objects are called *k*-reciprocal nearest neighbours of each other if they are among each other's *k*-nearest neighbours. I'm only interested in objects belonging to disjoint groups. For instance, consider two sets of numbers *S = {0, 1, 2}*, *T = {0.1, 1.1, 1.9}* and *k=2*. 
For group *S*,

- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *0* in *T* are *0.1, 1.1*.
- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *1* in *T* are *1.1, 1.9*.
- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *2* in *T* are *1.9, 2.1*.

And for group *T*,

- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *0.1* in *S* are *0, 1*.
- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *1.1* in *S* are *1, 2*.
- the *k*-nearest neighbours of *1.9* in *S* are *1, 2*.

Therefore the pairs of *k*-reciprocal nearest neighbours are *(0, 0.1), (1, 1.1), (1, 1.9), (2, 1.9)*.

---

Let *{A, B, C, D, E}* and *{W, X, Y, Z}* be two disjoint groups of some objects. Suppose that the Euclidean metric makes sense between these groups, and that we have the following *5x4* distance matrix:

```
distmat = np.array([[5,   1,   4, 7.5], 
                    [3,  10,   2,  11], 
                    [9, 2.5,   8,   3], 
                    [1,   3, 5.5,   5],
                    [4,   6, 3.5,   8]])
```

The five rows represent the distance of objects *A, B, C, D, E* from *W, X, Y, Z* correspondingly.

**Question:** What is an efficient way of obtaining the *k*-reciprocal nearest neighbours of *A* and of *B*?

Obtaining the *k*-nearest neighbours is ok, I used `np.argsort(distmat)` and then retrieved the objects with indices less than *k*.

Here's what I tried for the reciprocal part. wlog consider object *A*. For each *k*-nearest neighbour *N* of *A*, transpose `distmat` and check the *N*-th row. If *A* is a *k*-nearest neighbour of *N*, then they are reciprocals; otherwise they are not. Some rough code:

```
for index_N, N in enumerate(knn_A): 
    knn_N = get_knn(distmat.T[index_N]
    if A in knn_N: 
        print("{} and {} are {}-reciprocals".format(A, N, k))
```

Any suggestions for improvement? This is pretty slow because I have many nested for-loops already, and the size of the two groups is possibly large.

Comment: Could you clarify how reciprocal neareast neighbours works when you have two sets of objects, the first example uses only one set of numbers, while the question actually uses two disjoint sets.

Comment: Oops I wasn't being very clear. In the background info portion, compare the set against a copy of itself to yield a 4x4 distance matrix. The copy should be same in value but different in identity. Sorry, I'll only be able to edit the post tomorrow.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this problem. Wouldn't scipy already have functions implemented for this? See e.g. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors

Comment: The one I saw in scikit (called NearestNeighbours) treats the array row by row, but what I need is more element wise, so I felt that it wasn't suitable. This isn't a well-established problem, I just saw this concept being used in a paper and was interested in doing it too

Comment: You may kindly refer to https://github.com/zhunzhong07/person-re-ranking/blob/master/python-version/re_ranking_feature

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if this is faster since I don't see any nested for loops in the code you provided. Using your example ( which I think has the wrong reciprocal neighbors due to the line "the k-nearest neighbours of 2 in T are 1.9, 2.1." - where 2.1 is not in the set, and if you mean 1.1 then (2, 1.1) is also a reciprocal neighbor.

```
import numpy as np 
import itertools 

# set k and make the example set
k = 2
s1 = [0, 1, 2]
s2 = [.1, 1.1, 1.9]

#create the distance matrix 
newarray = [ [ abs(s2j-s1i) for s2j in s2] for s1i in s1]
distmat = np.array( newarray )

#get the nearest neighbors for each set 
neighbors_si = np.argsort( distmat )
neighbors_sj = np.argsort( distmat.T )

#map element of each set to k nearest neighbors
neighbors_si = { i: neighbors_si[i][0:k] for i in range(len(neighbors_si)) }
neighbors_sj = { j: neighbors_sj[j][0:k] for j in range(len(neighbors_sj)) }

#for each combination of i and j determine if they are in each others neighbor list
for i, j in itertools.product( neighbors_si.keys(), neighbors_sj.keys() ):
    if j in neighbors_si[i] and i in neighbors_sj[j]:
        print( '{} and {} are {}-reciprocals'.format( s1[i], s2[j], k ))
```